# GLM: Empirical cloglog transformation for exploratory data analysis

Tags: generalized-linear-model, data-transformation, link-function, cloglog

Prior to fitting a GLM to an ordered categorical response $Y$ (6 levels), I would like to check the linearity assumption between the one (and only) continuous covariate $x$ in my linear predictor and the transformed response, ie. $link(P_{obs})$.

After examining the distribution of $Y$, I am particularly interested in the complementary log-log link, which for an ordinal model, should be expressed as (Fahrmeir & Tutz, 2001):

$log[-log[P(Y>r|x)]]=\eta$

I get observed probabilities $P_{obs}(Y > r|x)=1-P_{obs}(Y \leq r|x)$ by creating $n$ bins, and for each bin taking the ratio between the cumulative count across the 6 levels and the total count.
So the observed probability for level 6, ie. $P_{obs}(Y \leq 6|x)$ is clearly always 1, meaning the above is not defined.

In Agresti (2002), I found an empirical transformation for the logit link function which deals with the similar issue of 0 or 1 observed probabilities. The formula given on p168 is the "least biased estimator" of the true logit function, and can be used as an empirical equivalent.

After much literature search, I cannot find an equivalent solution for the complementary log-log function. Is there a "least biased estimator" for this function? Else, a reasonable way of dealing with $P_{obs}(Y > r|x)=0$?

Fahrmeir & Tutz, 2001. Multivariate Statistical Modelling based on GLM, 2nd ed.
Agresti, 2002. Categorical Data Analysis, 2nd ed.

Comment: Given Y having 6 level, you just can model up to 5 level because , as you said, $P_{obs}(Y \leq 6|x) = 1$

Comment: Yes, it is true when I am at the stage of fitting the ordinal GLM - what I am wondering is how I check the linearity assumption prior to fitting the model for all the levels if I cannot plot $cloglog(P)$ vs. $x$ for each level... Are you saying that it is OK not to check linearity for level 6 (because we cannot)?

Comment: Yes. Do not need to check linearity of level 6.

Comment: Ok, I guess this can be considered a reference level. Thanks